# Wildfly - behaviour when reading configuration files

Tags: configuration, wildfly

We have been updating configuration files for standalone deployed applications inside a number of directories like this:

[wildfly]\modules\system\layers\base\com\\configurations\main\

But when we do so we create a copy of the previous version with a time and date stamp, for example:

appname\env-setup.properties
appname\env-setup_201912201230.properties

We have been advised this is not a good idea because these date and time stamped files will also be read and result in values being set incorrectly.

Is this correct? Where can we learn more regarding how these settings are read?

Comment: I've never seen any environment where you'd modify something in the `modules` directory regularly.  In a production environment that should be read-only.  What are you trying to do?  Can you show an example of the code you're using?

Comment: The configuration files are text files which contain settings such as the URLs for services consumed and credentials for those services. This means that the files are changed from time to time. When we make the change, we first copy the existing configuration file to the same directory with the filename modified to include a date and time stamp.
Our understanding is that the named file would be read by the module and so the files with different names would not be read. However it has been suggested to us that all files will be read. We need to understand the mechanisms by which this operates.

Comment: Depending on your code it sounds like it will only read the files you ask for.  I'd still recommend putting the files somewhere else like in your web app but that's your call.